# Understanding the opencart loader

Tags: php, opencart, classloader

Looking into opencart loader and trying to understand how it work. The opencart loader for loading/calling files

```
<?php
final class Loader {
    private $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function controller($route, $args = array()) {
        $action = new Action($route, $args);

        return $action->execute($this->registry);
    }

    public function model($model) {
        $file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/' . $model . '.php';
        $class = 'Model' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $model);

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            include_once($file);

            $this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $file . '!');
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function view($template, $data = array()) {
        $file = DIR_TEMPLATE . $template;

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            extract($data);

            ob_start();

            require($file);

            $output = ob_get_contents();

            ob_end_clean();

            return $output;
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load template ' . $file . '!');
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function library($library) {
        $file = DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/' . $library . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            include_once($file);
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load library ' . $file . '!');
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function helper($helper) {
        $file = DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/' . $helper . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            include_once($file);
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load helper ' . $file . '!');
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function config($config) {
        $this->registry->get('config')->load($config);
    }

    public function language($language) {
        return $this->registry->get('language')->load($language);
    }
}
```

This is the part that I am looking at

```
public function model($model) {
$file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/' . $model . '.php';
$class = 'Model' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $model);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    include_once($file);

    $this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));
} else {
    trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $file . '!');
    exit();
}
}
```

This is what I make out from the above code. When a model is called (assume the model name to be ModelA), the $file is set to catalog/model/ModelA.php and the $class to ModelModelA it then check if the file ($file) exist and if does it includes it (include_once ($file)).

What I do not understand is this part `$this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));`, What I make out of this is that it is trying to register the model file name but how?

If you see the index.php of the OC, there are a few registry done, like `$registry->set('db', $db)`. But this loader registry is confusing to me, I only get the first part `'model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model)` which converts 'ModelA' to 'Model_ModelA' but what does this `new $class($this->registry)` do ... new Model_ModelA($this->registry)?

What is $this->registry in new Model_ModelA($this->registry)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after spending a full day and going through a few articles I found and confirmed via a few test that what this does `$this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));` is actually registers the model as such in the registry system

```
$registry->set(model_ModelA, new model_ModelA($this->registry))
```

quite like others being registered on the index.php.